# DB2 restore unable to find DB2REMOTE path

Tags: database, amazon-s3, db2, database-restore

I am trying to do a DB2 restore using the following command:

```
db2 RESTORE DATABASE myd INCREMENTAL AUTOMATIC FROM DB2REMOTE://S3/mybucket/myfolder TAKEN AT 20200615212409
```

But this keeps failing with:

```
SQL2036N  The path for the file, named pipe, or device
"DB2REMOTE://S3/mybucket/myfolder" is not valid.
```

The bucket and the prefix do exist on AWS S3. Any pointers to what can I check? I have cataloged the storage access with correct credentials and I am able to list files from the bucket/folder.

```
# db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11054" with level 
identifier "0605010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.4.0", "s2006101300", "DYN2006101300PPCLE", 
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5.0.0".
```

DB2 diag logs show:

```
2020-06-16-17.15.41.909197-420 E921291E563          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 26849                TID : 17597173002592 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000           DB   : BLUDB
APPHDL  : 0-68                 APPID: *N0.db2inst1.200617001542
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: whisky-node0101
EDUID   : 1371                 EDUNAME: db2med.841.0 (BLUDB) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluMCCheckDevType, probe:189
MESSAGE : Media controller -- invalid device path: 
          DB2REMOTE://S3/mybucket/myfolder
```

OS: Centos 7

Storage alias:

```
[db2inst1@whisky-node0101 - Db2wh ~]$ db2 list storage access
 Node Directory
Node 1 entry:
ALIAS=S3
VENDOR=S3
SERVER=s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
USERID=XX
CONTAINER=mybucket
OBJECT=
DBUSER=db2inst1
DBGROUP=
```

Comment: EDIT your question to show your `catalog storage access` (redact the credentials and bucket names).  Please also check using format `DB2REMOTE://alias//storage-path/object` format (note two pairs of double slashes, you show a single / instead), or explain your alias (if region-alias/bucket/storage-path/file-name).

Comment: Tried using `DB2REMOTE://alias//storage-path/object` but still the same error.

Comment: The text after DB2REMOTE:// would match that used for the successful prior Db2-backup command as long as the storage-access command was same between source-Db2-instance and target-Db2-instance.